# Como passar mais de um argumento usando o Process + OpenSSL

Tags: .net, vb.net, openssl, processo

Usando o seguinte código eu passo um certo argumento, em seguida preciso passar uma senha que o OpenSSL solicita, mas como faço isso? Tentei o `StandardInput` mas recebi uma exceção:

> Informações adicionais: StandardIn não foi redirecionado

```
 Dim procAssin As New Process()
    With procAssin.StartInfo
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")

        .FileName = "C:\OpenSSL\openssl.exe"

        .WorkingDirectory = "C:\certificado\bin"

        .Arguments = "pkcs12 -in C:\Cert\certificado.pfx -out C:\Cert\certificado.pem -nodes"

    End With

    procAssin.Start()

  procAssin.StandardInput.WriteLine("SENHA")
```

Comment: Experimentou adicionar ` myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;` também?

Comment: Realmente, era isso. Falta de atenção minha. 
Não deu mais o erro, porém não adicionou a senha também, e estranho que quando abre o console eu tambem não consigo escrever nele, tem ideia o que pode ser?

Comment: Eu respondi para não deixar a pergunta em aberto.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Ligando esta propriedade resolve:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ProcessRedirect.cs).